# Autofill UserId on AngularJS Login Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wkwebview, autofill

I'm working on a iOS app that uses a WKWebView to log into a website.  The website presents a login form written in AngularJS that takes a UserId and Password.  I'm attempting to pre-fill the UserId using javascript to fill in the appropriate value:

```
document.getElementsByName('UserId')[0].value = 'MyUserId'
```

Once submitted, the form returns 'invalid credentials' as if the userid input field has been left blank. If I subsequently make any manual changes to the UserId input field and resubmit it works.

I have verified that the UserId does contain the correct value.  I have also tried to change the AngularJS field attributes prior to submitting the form:

```
ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required
```

Within my javascript code, I make sure to convert the UserId to a javascript compatible string:

```
UserId.toString()
```

Manually typing the UserId and autofill from 1Password works as expected.

I would appreciate any suggestions or advice.

The angular code for the form:

---

```
<form class="spark-splash-screen__form spark-text-left ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" novalidate="" name="loginCtrl.loginForm" ng-submit="loginCtrl.submitForm()">
            <p class="spark-margin-top--lg spark-margin-bottom" translate="">Sign In to.</p>
            <label class="spark-input" fang-input="" ng-class="{
                            'active': loginCtrl.formData.id
                         }">
                <input class="spark-input__field ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="UserId" placeholder="Enter User ID..." role="textbox" required="" ng-model="loginCtrl.formData.id" autofocus="">
                <span class="spark-label">User ID</span>
            </label>
            <label class="spark-input" fang-input="" ng-class="{
                            'active': loginCtrl.formData.password
                         }">
                <input type="password" class="spark-input__field ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" name="Password" placeholder="What is your password?" role="textbox" required="" ng-model="loginCtrl.formData.password">
                <span class="spark-label">Password</span>
                <span class="spark-input__addon spark-input__password-toggle">
                    <i class="spark-input__password-show spark-icon--md spark-icon-password-view"></i>
                    <i class="spark-input__password-hide spark-icon--md spark-icon-password-hide"></i>
                </span>
            </label>
            <fieldset class="row">
                <label class="col-xs-12 spark-checkbox">
                    <input class="spark-checkbox__input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" ng-model="loginCtrl.formData.rememberMe">
                    <span class="spark-checkbox__box"></span>
                    <span class="spark-label" translate="">Remember Me</span>
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 spark-margin-top">
                    <button type="submit" class="spark-btn spark-btn--md spark-btn--primary spark-block--lte-sm spark-margin-bottom--md spark-pull-right--gte-sm" ng-disabled="loginCtrl.formSubmiting" translate="">Sign In</button>
                    <div class="spark-splash-screen__help-container spark-pull-left--gte-sm">
                        <button type="button" class="spark-btn spark-btn--text spark-splash-screen__help spark-margin-bottom--sm" translate="" ng-click="loginCtrl.openDialog('findUserOrPass')">Forgot User ID or Password?</button>
                        <button type="button" class="spark-btn spark-btn--text spark-splash-screen__help spark-margin-bottom--sm" translate="" ng-click="loginCtrl.openDialog('firstTimeUser')">First-Time User</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is the answer I figured out after being pointed in the right direction:

```
document.getElementsByName('UserId')[0].value = useridField;
    angular.element(document.getElementsByName('UserId')).scope().loginCtrl.formData.id = useridField;
```

Comment: can you put angular code here??

Comment: Edited question to include angular code for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try also assigning the ng-model (loginCtrl.formData.id)

From loginCtrl, which I assume is the controller:

```
document.getElementsByName('UserId')[0].value = 'MyUserId';
formData.id = 'MyUserId';
```

If you're doing this asynchronously, you may need to $apply:

```
document.getElementsByName('UserId')[0].value = 'MyUserId';
$scope.$apply(function() {
  formData.id = 'MyUserId';
});
```

Comment: That didn't work, but you pointed me in the right direction!  I didn't understand how angular created its data binding model.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: I needed to access the loginForm scope and add the value there as well as filling it in the form: angular.element(document.getElementsByName('UserId')).scope().loginCtrl.formData.id = useridField;

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I figured out after being pointed in the right direction:

```
document.getElementsByName('UserId')[0].value = useridField;
angular.element(document.getElementsByName('UserId')).scope().loginCtrl.formData.id = useridField;
```